# Сортировка с помощью лямбда-выражений

Tags: java

Как отсортировать массив(лист) строк с помощью лямбды по убыванию?

Comment: Это не сайт помощи студентам/школьникам в учебе. Покажите свои наработки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    тут код, сравнивающий объекты из листа.
    возвращает отрицательное число, если o1 < o2,
    ноль, если равны и положительное число, если o2 > o1
    (для чисел можно просто return o1 - o2;)
});
```